# Preview a few rows from another tab, information taken from a database

Tags: android, native

Just pointing out that I do not have adequate skills for android studio to know what terms to use for this issue.

To my question:

I want to have a preview window in one tab that refers to the, say, top three rows from another tab in the same app. When you click on the preview you jump to the other tab. The information itself comes from a database. 
Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8rWC.png

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You stated what you want to achieve but you didn't ask a question. Here are [some hints on how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please keep in mind that SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Have you tried some of the Tab and ListView examples, like [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) or [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/)?

Comment: Thanks gus27, the list info is solid! I already got the tabs set up, sorry for not mentioning that before.